# Intellij IDEA is not able to detect jdk what to do?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, intellij-idea, java-11

I have recently moved from windows to ubuntu-22.04 and it is a bit confusing.
I have installed intellij IDEA, after installing java and jdk, but still intellij is not able to detect the jdk version installed in my pc.[intellij not detecting jdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7sUZ.png)
The path of installed java is also set but still it is not working in intellij.[Path of installed java.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVgeY.png) what should I do, I am not able to use intellij IDEA for java programming.

I have tried setting up the path in .bashrc file but still there is no change in intellij IDEA.
[.bashrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wybCB.png).

Comment: How about you "Add one" and follow the prompts?

Comment: Use the "add jdk" option and navigate to the jdk installation folder.

Comment: Your shell settings are correct, though the jdk is not recent. If IntelliJ is *Intelli*gent, your jdk should be in the list ready to Add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screen of your first screenshot, Click "Download JDK", then select the version you need.

What you might already have installed is the Java Runtime